# Device file for USB controller/joystick not created

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, usb, kernel

I've got an Android 4.1.2 device (OUYA) and a PSX-USB-Adapter with two Playstation controllers attached. Attaching it to the USB port makes the device show up in `dmesg`:

```
<6>[  331.002934] usb 2-1: new low speed USB device number 13 using tegra-ehci
<6>[  331.039183] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0810, idProduct=0001
<6>[  331.046013] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
<6>[  331.053437] usb 2-1: Product: Twin USB Joystick
```

Unfortunately, no device files in `/dev/input/` like `/dev/input/js0` are created.

Who/which part of android is responsible for detecting that an USB device is a joystick and creating the corresponding input files?

Btw, the controllers are detected fine on a standard Linux (Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the necessary kernel modules were not compiled in (I checked that in `/proc/config.gz`).

See http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ouya-usb-joysticks.htm for information about compiling your own kernel with the modules.